# Hibernate Many To One mapping to a Many To One column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, many-to-one

I have the following three simplified classes that represent a relationship I need to map in a legacy database I'm working with.

```
class One
{
  @Id
  String id
}

class Two
{ 
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = 'ONE', referencedColumn = 'ID')
  One one
}

class Three
{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = 'TWO', referencedColumn = 'ONE')
  Two two
}
```

The relationship between class One and Two works fine, however, the relationship between class Two and Three doesn't work.  Hibernate returns a "Unable to find column with logical name: ONE in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TWO) and its related supertables and secondary tables" error.  I've debugged into the hibernate code to where this error gets thrown and the org.hibernate.mapping.Table object that defines the TWO table doesn't contain any column details.  It not treating the Many To One join in the Two class as a column.